# SQL: counting the number of rows and returning all rows with max count: invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have these tables:

**tutors**:

```
tutorid firstname, lastname...
```

**courses**:

```
url  tutorid
```

**reviews**:

```
review courseid
```

I need to select all tutors that have the most reviews. 1 tutor = 1 course. 
I first tried to just select courses with the most reviews:

```
select y.courseid, num from (select courseid,COUNT(reviews.rating) as num 
from reviews group by (reviews.courseid)) y;
```

This selects all urls and the number of reviews for each.

this

```
select y.courseid, MAX(num) from (select courseid,COUNT(reviews.rating) as num 
from reviews group by (reviews.courseid)) y;
```

would display the single course with most reviews - even if there are other courses with the same (maximum) number of reviews - they won't get displayed.

I'm trying to combat that. I tried

```
select y.courseid, num from (select courseid,COUNT(reviews.rating) as num 
from reviews group by (reviews.courseid)) y
where num = MAX(num);
```

but get `invalid use of group function` error.

**EDIT**: the courseid - is the course's url. As in the course's url is the foreign key in the reviews table.

Comment: You want tutors with most reviews, but your schema shows no way of linking those two things

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this one:

```
select distinct t.tutorid t.firstname, t.lastname
from (select courseid, count(reviews.rating) total
           from reviews
           group by courseid) r
left join courses c
on r.courseid = c.courseid
left join tutors t
on c.tutorid = t.tutorid
where r.total=(select max(total)
                         from  (select courseid, 
                         count(reviews.rating) total
                         from reviews
                         group by courseid) r 
                        )
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL which doesn't seem to support WITH. Other than that if I just duplicate the total_reviews query, it seems to be working!

Comment: Also there's a problem with that if there are two courses with the same tutor and the same number of reviews, it returns 2 rows with the name of the same tutor, while it should just return 1 name in that case.

Comment: I've updated my solution to be without `with` clause and I've added `distinct` to prevent dups for tutors

Answer (score 1):

You can create a column that rank the review in desc order and select those tutor with rank = 1
It would look like this:

Select * from(Select *, rank() over(order by num desc) as rank from table) where rank = 1

You can also use dense_rank base on your need.